# Rails Migration Create table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, database-migration

I have a very simple migration script in rails,

```
class CreateGeocode < ActiveRecord::Migration
def up
  create_table :geocodes do |t|      
    t.string :zip_code, :null => false
    t.float :latitude
    t.float :longitude
    t.string :country_code
    t.timestamps      
  end
end

def down
    drop_table :geocodes
end
end
```

When i migrate this to DB. It creates a table with name geocodes. Now, when i try to insert a record in it like,

```
 g = Geocode.new(:zip_code => '27606')
 g.save
```

through rails console, this is the result which i get,

```
mysql> select * from geocodes;

+-------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
| id    | zip_code | latitude | longitude | country_code | created_at          | updated_at          |
+-------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
| 27606 | 27606    |     NULL |      NULL | NULL         | 2013-01-17 08:10:34 | 2013-01-17 08:10:34 |
+-------+----------+----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------+---------------------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why id is taking the same value as that of zipcode?

Any guess ?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer on my own, as i found my mistake in the code.

Accidentally i set zip_code as primary key in model.
This is why the scenario is happening.

That was my mistake. Rails wastreating zip_code+id as the primary key and setting same value to both id and zip_code.